# How do I access functions from a class in another jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, scope

I know a good bit about Javascript but this particular thing escapes me. Effectively I have a class like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// jQuery Object
var $ = jQuery;

// A general class for a general file.
var MyClass = function() {
    // ...      
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    init: function() {
        // ...
    }
}


new generalClass();

});
```

I'm including this file in the head of my document like this, as well as calling another jQuery object like this:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     MyClass.prototype.init();
});
</script>
```

There are some functions in MyClass (as shown above) that I want to call in this second jQuery function but since the scope is different I can't access it. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Declare `var MyClass` in global scope, initialize it within the anonymous function you passed to `$(document).ready` and then access it from your second `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: Note: a better shortcut for a DOM ready handler *and* a locally scoped `$` is `jQuery(function($){your code here});`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: That *is* a `ready` handler.

Comment: @scheisse_minelli: That's at least third on a list of at least three alternatives. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That is why I upvoted your answer :D

Comment: @scheisse_minelli: LOL! ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: yes, and that was just suggesting the better/shorter shortcut version (with a locally scoped $). Not suggesting it as a fix to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either define the two so that they are within a common scoping function (which would be your `ready` callback or just something you execute at the end of `body`), or (and this is very much a lesser alternative) export `MyClass` as a global, or use some third-party global (for instance, RequireJS's `require` and `define`). Unless you do one of those things, there's no way for the code in the second `ready` callback to access the private symbols contained by the first `ready` callback.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is declared inside a function then it's scope will be inside that function only. Unless you declare it globally (outside the function).

**script.js**

```
// A general class for a general file.
var MyClass = function() {
  // ...      
};

MyClass.prototype = {
  init: function() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note: there is no `$(document).ready` since we don't really need it to create a class, or run any javascript that's not intervening with the DOM.

**HTML**

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   MyClass.prototype.init();
});
</script>
```